# Check if Uri points to a file or directory

Tags: android, uri

How do we check if an Android Uri(android.net.Uri) object points to a file or a directory, assuming that the Uri exists?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the URI and identify is it file or not.

```
val pointToFile = uri.scheme == "file"
```

Comment: Isn't the Uri scheme pointing to the source of the file(e.g. content://, http://)? Wouldn't the scheme be same for files and directories?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open an InputStream for the uri.

If you succeed it's a file.

Don't forget to close the stream.

Further you can use a content resolver to query for mime type. There exists mime type dir.

Comment: This method is feasible, but what if the Uri is a file but cannot be accessed for some reason(e.g. security permissions)? The input stream would fail to be created.

Comment: What are you doing with uries that cannot be accessed or used?

Comment: I think the 2nd method is better. What is the mime type of a directory? Is it "vnd.android.document/directory"?

Comment: I just want to make sure that a file will not be detected as a directory when the file cannot be accessed.

Comment: Yes that looks like a directory mime type. You wiil soon have no doubt about that if you do some queries.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you update your answer to include the query mime type method, including what mime type should be used? I can mark it as the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: With the comments it is ok as it is now.

Comment: By the way, how do I use a content resolver to query for mime type? The uri I am using is not a MediaStore uri, but a Uri returned by the Storage Access Framework. I tried getContentResolver.getType(uri) and it returned null.

Comment: If you wanna query then use query() instead.

Comment: I used query(), but I got  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri

Comment: You should post your code in your post. (Not in a comment please) `but a Uri returned by the Storage Access Framework. ` You got it in onActivityResulr? Then post full code.

Comment: instead of hardcoding "vnd.android.document/directory", you can use this DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR constant instead. cc @LCZ

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this soon.